# Attach Google Search specific favicon to HTML

Tags: html, seo

On the Google Search result for my website, the favicon shows a square inside a circular container, this looks bad and doesn't give off the right look for my site, but I like how it looks in the tabs. Is there a way where I can make the tab show a square favicon, and for search to show a circular one?

My guess is changing something with the meta tags or editing manifest.json but I'm not sure where to start

[How my favicon looks in a Safari tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcHuA.jpg)

[How my favicon looks in search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY0C7.jpg)

This is what my HTML meta tags look like

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/48.png" sizes="48x48">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/180.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/512.png" sizes="512x512">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon/maskable_icon_x128.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="media/favicon/maskable_icon_x128.png">
```

This is how my icons look in manifest.json

```json
"icons": [
      {
        "src": "media/favicon/maskable_icon_x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "media/favicon/maskable_icon_x128.png",
        "sizes": "128x128",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "media/favicon/maskable_icon_x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "media/favicon/180.png",
        "sizes": "180x180",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
      },
      {
        "src": "media/favicon/512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Read more https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search and https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/logo

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right. In fact, I would probably link people to your post because you provided a great example of how to implement favicons in a website.

---

You want Google to immediately update the favicon for your website. That is where the issue comes. Google will only periodically crawl/scrape/analyze your website. When your website appears on the search results page, Google does not feel a need to re-crawl your website, because it's already done so. Because of this, Google simply provides the user with the information it already has on your website, and this includes the favicon.

You have two options at this point:

1. Wait for Google to re-analyze your website
2. Request that Google re-anlyze your website with a higher priority

If you choose to go the Option 1 route, then you don't need to do anything. If you choose to go the Option 2 route, then you'll have to use the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about). Also note that Google will not immediately start re-scanning your site. Google has possibly hundreds of thousands of these requests a day and they have to fulfill all of them. Additionally, Google will higher prioritize well-known and popular sites that have constant updates over smaller, less visited sites. Putting your request in today may mean that they will re-analyze your site tomorrow rather than next week or next month.